# How to setup postgres admin user on mac os x?

Tags: macos, postgresql

I just installed postgresql on my mac (lion) using homebrew, and when I use the `psql postgres` (or any other database), it automatically logs me in.

Funny thing is, even if change the password once in psql using the `\password` command, it still just lets me in without prompting me for a password.

It also shows my user name (same user name as my mac os login) as the owner.

Is there a way to secure things a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgresql is most likely configured to trust anyone. This is configured int the file pg_hba.conf which is located in the data directory of postgresql. I do not know where homebrew places the data dir. However if you issue the following command in a terminal:

```
ps aux | grep postmaster
```

you will get a response like:

```
postgres          63   0,0  0,1  2472288   4888   ??  Ss   12:19pm   0:00.85 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/data
```

The part after -D is the location of your data directory. You might have to resize your terminal to make it fit.

Open the pg_hba.conf with your favorite editor like:

```
sudo vi <datadir>/pg_hba.conf
```

The file contains (on all installations I have seen) a fair bit of comment describing the settings. The actual settings are a the bottom of the file. I suspect that one or more of those lines end in trust. Change these into md5 to get password verification.

Comment: The easy way to find the pg_hba.conf file is to connect and execute `show pg_hba.conf;`. Documentation for the file is http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: @kgrittn: that doesn't work for me. But it gave me the idea to look for what it could show and this one is helpful `show data_directory;`

Comment: Sorry about that; caffeine hadn't really kicked in. What I meant to type was `show hba_file;'. The file may or may not be in the data directory -- some packaged distributions put all configuration files in or under the /etc/ directory.

Comment: I was able to find the file using the 'show data_directory;' command.   I modified everything at the bottom to md5, but it still lets me in.  Do I need to reboot?

Comment: BTW, the directory I found it in was: /usr/local/var/postgres